# AudioSource playes when press fire spacebar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class GunLaser: MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource playAudio;
    private bool isActive = true;

    void Start()
    {
        playAudio = FindObjectOfType<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isActive)
        {
            ProcessFiring();
        }
    }

    void ProcessFiring()
    {
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("Fire"))
        {
            SetAudioSourceActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            SetAudioSourceActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void SetAudioSourceActive(bool isActive)
    {
         playAudio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
         playAudio.enabled = isActive;
    }
}
```

When I press the fire/spacebar and hold it down the audiosource stops playing but if I stay tapping the fire/spacebar it plays. How can I get it to play when I hold down the fire/spacebar? Any insight is apperciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way you could do is:

```
void Update()
    {    
       if(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
           playAudio.Play()

       if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
           playAudio.Stop()
    }
```

instead of enabling and disabling the audiosource, you could've use audiosource play and stop.

Comment: @MartinAntonetty if this answer solves your question please mark it as the accepted answer using the `✔`